# Ajax returns value but function returns null

Tags: javascript, ajax

**functions.js**

```
function clients(id){
    var result = '';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "classes/response.php?type=clients",
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(data){
            result = data;
            console.log(result); // retrieves 'John'
            console.log(data);   // retrieves 'John'
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

And in my other file **main.js**

```
$("#client_check").on('click', function(){

     var input = $("#client_id");
     var name  = clients(input.val());

     console.log(name); // retrieves empty

     $("#client_id").val('');

});
```

Shouldn't this work? The function output the value perfectly, but when I call the function to a variable it retrieves empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're returning the result when the ajax call is still running

Comment: asynchronous javascript and xml is asynchronous

Comment: $.ajax({
        async: false,

Comment: @RajeshCP — Oh no. Locking up the JS event loop while waiting for the HTTP response is an awful idea.

Comment: @Quentin noted, just out of curiosity then why exactly that option ?

Comment: @RajeshCP — It's been in there for 14 years, removing it would break backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, My changes only `callback` function rest is as per OP

```
function clients(id,callBack){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "classes/response.php?type=clients",
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(data){
            result = data;
            console.log(result); // retrieves 'John'
            console.log(data);   // retrieves 'John'
            callBack(data);
        }
    });
}


$("#client_check").on('click', function(){

     var input = $("#client_id");
     clients(input.val(),function(name){
        console.log(name);
     });
     $("#client_id").val('');

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved according to: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

```
function clients(id){
    return 
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "classes/response.php?type=clients",
          data: {id: id},
      });
}
// And to call it:
clients(input.val()).done(function(r){
    console.log(r);
});
```